# Carousel out of alignment with rest of website anyone care to help me

Tags: html, css, alignment, carousel

See the below images:

the website as viewed in chrome
http://i48.tinypic.com/2rr9zf7.png

the website as viewed in dreamweaver:
http://i50.tinypic.com/mcvey9.png

The problem is the carousel doesnt line up with the navbar at the top (see top right). 
it seems to be out of line by 1mm

I believe it may have to do something with the navbar (see second image). As you can see the contact button falls below the rest of the buttons.

my theory is that its causing the carousel to be out of alignment.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<link href="../CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

<div id="outer">

<a href="file:///C|/Users/Callum/Desktop/desktop/website folder/WEBSITE/main.html"><img src="../Images/webimages/banner top.jpg"  /></a>

</div>

<div id="topnav">

<ul id="list-nav">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Technologies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>

<div id="carousel">

<iframe src="../Carousel/HTML/carousel.html" height="280" width="900" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> </iframe>

</div>
<div id="mainbody">  
<div id="bigbuttons">

<img src="../Images/webimages/Meettheteam.jpg">

</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset */

a img {
 border: none;
}

html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

img.floatLeft { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0px; 
}

*
{
   margin:  0;
   padding: 0;
}

body {background-color:#F1F1F1; }

#outer { width: 900px; margin: auto; }

#topnav { width: 900px; margin: auto; }

#mainbody { width: 900px; margin:auto; clear:both; } 

#list-nav li{display:inline-block;width:20%;float:left;}

#carousel { width: 900px; height: 280px; margin:auto; clear:both; }

#bigbuttons { width: 220px; height: 80px; margin:auto; margin-top: 9px; clear:both; float:left }

ul#list-nav li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:5px 0;
 width: auto;
 background:#999;
 color:#eee;
 float: left
}

ul#list-nav li a {
  text-align:center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background:#CCC;
  color:#ffff;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background:#CCC;
  color:#ffff;
}

#content-fullwidth { width:100%; }​
```

Comment: How is looks in dreamweaver is irrelevant since it is not a real browser.

Comment: Your sample code can't be run, it's using local URL's.

Comment: [Make one of these](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Im sorry, im really new to coding. i gave a comparison to show how they look in dreamweaver compared to how it looks in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code for the carousel that you are filling the iframe with.  Looks like your issue is there, not with the code you have provided us.